# Создал метод, заполнил его содержимым. Ссылку на метод разместил в oncreate, но содержимое его не видит программа

Tags: java, android, методы

Создал метод который заполняет `List` картинками

```
public void findResurs(){
        List<Integer> arrImage = new ArrayList<>();
        arrImage.add(R.drawable.img1);
        arrImage.add(R.drawable.img2);
        arrImage.add(R.drawable.img3);
```

Затем поместил этот метод в `oncreate`где он и должен работать. Но содержимое его `arrImage` там не работает.

```
// размещаю метод
findResurs();

// здесь вроде как должен работать, но arrImage красным цветом
int length = title.length;
persons = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    persons.add(new Person(i, title[i],   arrImage.get(i)));
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`class Person` - к вопросу не имеет никакого отношение, но вдруг кому-то будет интересно, что это

```
public class Person {

    long id;
    String title;
    int photoId;

    // пустой конструктор
    public Person() {
    }

    // конструктор с переменными

    public Person(long id, String title,  int photoId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.photoId = photoId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Список arrImage  находиться внутри метода findResurs и не виден из вне. Сделай его частью класса или пусть твой метод findResurs возвращяет созданый список и сохрание его в новом List объекте

Comment: Видимо, слово отладчик ТС неизвестно и нам всем предлагается побыть отладчиком

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно выделяет красным, это же не его область видимости.

Переменная/ссылка видна только в рамках тех фигурных скобок, в которых она объявлена, а также в последующих вложенных блоках.

Нужно, чтобы метод `findResurs()` возвращал результат:

```
public List<Integer> findResurs() {
        List<Integer> arrImage = new ArrayList<>();
        arrImage.add(R.drawable.img1);
        arrImage.add(R.drawable.img2);
        arrImage.add(R.drawable.img3);
        return arrImage;
}
```

А затем, в активити:

```
List<Integer> arrImage = findResurs();
```

Комментарии по поводу нецелесообразности хранения идентификаторов изображений-ресурсов в модели я опущу.

Comment: Спасибо Владимир, я уже дня три голову себе ломал, что не так. Решил вопрос на части разбить. Но с этим вроде разобрался как тоже самое проделать с String[] title = res.getStringArray(R.array.titleString);